# parsing json & mapping xml with java com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;

Tags: java, json, jackson

New to java here coming from .NET and having some issue with parsing json. I need to be able to verify that a node exists and that the value is also not null before attempting to try and retrieve the value. I tried the following but not sure if this is the best approach.

```
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    JsonNode messageNode = mapper.readTree(post);

        id = messageNode.path("id").asText();
    author = messageNode.path("actor").get("displayName").asText();
    authorId = messageNode.path("actor").get("id").asText();
    authorLink = messageNode.path("actor").get("link").asText();

    if (! messageNode.path("actor").get("link").isMissingNode()) {
        imageLink = messageNode.path("actor").get("link").asText();
    }

    pauthor = messageNode.path("actor").get("preferredUsername").asText();
```

Do I just use this for each field but how do I also check for null value?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you should benefit from using [JsonNode.has(...)](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.3.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html#has%28java.lang.String%29) and [JsonNode.hasNotNull(...)](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.3.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html#hasNonNull%28java.lang.String%29) methods.

Comment: So I would have to check each field for null and if node exists?

Comment: I suppose so. You should check that a node exists before you accessing its value to avoid getting a NullPointerException.